# Internal system error

Tags: system

installing Ubuntu 14.04.1 or 14.10 in VMware workstation 10, when i reboot the system, always remind me that there are internal system errors, i don't know why, who can tell me the reason, thank you very much.

Sorry, my reputation is weak, i can't post images, the warning is "System program problem detected   Do you want to report the problem now?"

Comment: It would be helpful to know what error is being reported.  The Ubuntu window indicating an internal error has a 'Show Details' box, which can be used to give you a little information about what the error is.

Comment: Sorry, my reputation is weak, i can't post images, the warning is "System program problem detected Do you want to report the problem now?"

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the exact error it's hard to tell, but a guess is could be filesystem errors, though ubuntu is usually good about running fsck on bootup when it needs to, running it manually might help (maybe from a live iso/cd, easy to boot from an iso in VirtualBox, VMware maybe too?) See if the system logs say anything about bootup errors, like `dmesg` &/or `/var/log/syslog`, anything interesting in `/var/log/`

Being run in VMware I'd hope there wouldn't be any filesystem errors, I thought VMware handles the "virtual" hard disk itself.

New info:

> the warning is "System program problem detected Do you want to report the problem now?" –  holly

That sounds like a message firefox often gives when it crashes, it's crash reporter program detects and gives that message. I'm not sure exactly which program it is though, "System" is very vague. You could try updating the software / packages, that could fix the offending program? I'd hate to suggest reinstalling Ubuntu (this isn't windows!) but maybe testing the same setup with a new VM, if same error happens would mean a bug (or error in your iso if installing from live disk & no updating)?

And there should still be some clues in `dmesg` or the log files above, when a program crashes there's usually a line like "... segfault at .... in lib..." (with the "..."'s being probably gibberish-looking memory addresses and codes).

Comment: Sorry, i'm a new user, i can't post images, the warning is "System program problem detected Do you want to report the problem now?"